# Serial source code

Tags: serial

`Serial` is documented on the Reference pages, but seems to receive special treatment (no need to include header), and there does not seem to be any file with the Source code.

`Stream` is the base class for `Serial` and inherits from the Print class.

There is source for `Stream.h`

`LiquidCrystal_I2C` also inherits from the Print class, and I was planning to write code which outputs to either `LiquidCrystal_I2C` or `Serial`; there are many options, but I was looking for `Serial` to explore its inner workings.

Comment: The `HardwareSerial.cpp` file is located in `...hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino`, if that is what you are looking for

Comment: @Fauzan There is no `Serial` class in the location above, which is where I found the other source.

Comment: Serial is an instance of class HardwareSerial.

Comment: @Majenko Where is it defined? I cannot even find the symbol `Serial` anywhere?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h#L143 is where Serial is defined. On AVR MCUs with built-in USB it is defined here https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/USBAPI.h#L152.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Serial` is an *instance* of the `HardwareSerial` class.  It is defined in `HardwareSerial0.cpp`:

```
#if defined(UBRRH) && defined(UBRRL)
  HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR);
#else
  HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L, &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
#endif
```

`HardwareSerial` is a child of `Stream` as defined in `HardwareSerial.h`:

```
class HardwareSerial : public Stream
{
    ....
};
```

`Stream` is a child of `Print` as defined in `Stream.h`:

```
class Stream : public Print
{
    ....
};
```

`Print` is a top-level class with no inheritance.

`Serial` is *not* a class. It is an *instance* of a class. That is, it's an object that has been *constructed* from the class definition. Anything you access member functions of using a `.` is an *instance* of a class (aka an *object*) not a class itself. Anything you access member functions with `::` is a class using *static* member functions.

Examples:

```
Serial.println(); // Call the println() function in the Serial object
Wire.beginTransmission(0x34); // Call the beginTransmission function in the Wire object
Foo::bar(); // Call the static function bar() in the Foo class.
```